# Wildfly JDBC XA validate on match timeout

Tags: java, jdbc, wildfly

We have a wildfly application accesing a an Azure postgreSQl Flexible server database.

Conection works fine but sometimes, when microsoft performs a manteinance of the server they generate an unavailability of about 1-2minutes.

Our datasource validation config is like this:

```
<validation>
         <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
         <valid-connection-checker 
    classname="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
</validation>
```

Althoug the application is able to recover connections after database unavailability, i was wondering, in order to avoid an error to users, if we can somehow set a timeout or retries when providing a new connection to the database.

May be with: [docs.wildfly.org](https://docs.wildfly.org/19/wildscribe/deployment/subsystem/datasources/xa-data-source/index.html#attr-allocation-retry)

- allocation-retry The allocation retry element indicates the number of times that allocating a connection should be tried before throwing an exception
- allocation-retry-wait-millis The allocation retry wait millis element specifies the amount of time, in milliseconds, to wait between retrying to allocate a connection

Any experience using those parameters with validation-on-match?

Thank you in advance.